# Why would a credit card company reject a transaction for suspected fraud, but not contact me?

Tags: fraud, debit-card

My bank offers a debit card, which I can use to perform online purchases. Recently, I tried to purchase clothing online, but the card was declined. I was certain that I had enough funds on the card, so I checked online and indeed, I had way more on my bank account than the sum of the purchase (which in and of itself was quite low, under 100€).

I repeated my attempt to purchase the clothing, but I got rejected again. I waited several day, then attempted the purchase again. And yet again, I was rejected. So I called my bank and asked why my purchases are getting rejected. My bank contact told me the charges were rejected because they were marked as possibly fraudulent (which they weren't).

I asked why I was not informed by the credit card company - after all, they suspected my card was stolen. My bank contact could not answer that.

So my question is: If my credit card company believes that my card was stolen, why are they not contacting me? And if they *don't* believe my card was stolen, why would my payment to a commonly known online store be rejected?

Comment: the question starts talking about a debit card but then seems to switch to talking about a credit card (company). Did you mean bank rather than credit card company?

Comment: The debit card is provided by the bank, but it's branded "master card". The bank also says the debit card is a master card product. Sorry if I expressed myself weirdly. English is not my native language.

Comment: most banks allow you to customize your notifications. Did you check whether  notifications for this type of thing are enabled?

Comment: @Hilmar I could not find anything related to that in the online banking portal. I assume my bank does not offer such a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If my credit card company believes that my card was stolen, why are they not contacting me?

They don't believe the card was stolen, they believe the transaction was unauthorized.

Usually this happens automatically through some fraud detection system in your bank that analyzes transactions and usage patterns and tries to make an educated guess as to whether the transaction is genuine or not.

The goal is to avoid liability for the bank, so if the transaction is suspected to be fraudulent - it is rejected. If it is important enough for you - you'll call yourself, just as you did. Adding a human into the process to call every affected cardholder on any affected transaction would be cost prohibitive, and the goal after all is to reduce costs.

Comment: That's weird, because I need to use a 2FA app with a pin and fingerprint to authorize transactions over 50€. So the provider knows that I have access to my 2FA app on my phone, my fingerprint *and* my pin. It just seems wild to me that they'd go that far to validate that it's really me, and then *still* reject the transaction.